# RMSE calculation after binning using matlab

Tags: matlab, binning, goodness-of-fit

Hi I want to calculate the RMSE but it seems that I am making some logical mistake.This is my given below code :

```
topEdge = 20; % upper limit 
botEdge = 5; % lower limit
numBins = 40;   % define number of bins 
b_vector = speed; a_vector = power;
[N,edges,bins] = histcounts(b_vector,numBins);
Pow_means = [];
speed_means = [];

  For n = 1:numBins
    Pow_means(n,1) = mean(a_vector(bins==n,1));  % for each bins mean value calculation.
   speed_means(n,1) = mean(b_vector(bins==n,1));  % for each bins mean value calculation.
   pow_std(n,1) = std(a_vector(bins==n,1));       % for Standard deviation calculation
  end
```

`residual = power -Pow_means; 
      RMSE = rms(residual);
     variation = RMSE/mean(power);`

Is my approach to calculate RMSE is correct ?? or what correction I have to make to calculate RMSE

Comment: What is `rms`? Is that your own function or a variable defined by you?

Comment: rms is root mean square as defined by matlab and RMSE is root mean square error